# How can I persist an Oracle Machine Learning (OML) k-means model?

Tags: oracle, machine-learning, k-means

This example doesn’t show how to save the k-means cluster model into the database. Is there a way to do that and is there example code for it?

[Oracle Machine Learning for Python](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4py/1/mlpug/k-means.html#GUID-7909D96B-D3B9-411B-BAD5-96DAFAF06B42)

Here's how I create the model,

```
# Create a KM model object and fit it.
km_mod = oml.km(n_clusters = 3, **setting).fit(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the model_name parameter. To provide a persistent model name during the model build:

```
km_mod = oml.km(n_clusters = 3, **setting).fit(data, model_name = "MY_KM_MODEL")
```

Or, rename a model with a new user-specified model name:

```
km_mod.model_name = 'MY_KM_MODEL'
km_mod.model_name
 'MY_KM_MODEL'
```